# How to use swiper in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

Hi how can I have a swiper working in a `Profil` Component using the data from a `Home` component. I have a state in `Home` component where I stock data from a webservice.

```
class Accueil extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      latitude:null,
      longitude:null,
      dataSource:[],
      error:null,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      currentIndex: 0,
    }
    this.displayPosition = this.displayPosition.bind(this);
  }

getData(){
    fetch("SomeURL")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        return(
        this.setState({
          dataSource: result
        }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
          <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData = {this.state}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.MembreId}
          renderItem={(item) => <UserItem user={item} displayDetailForUser={this._displayDetailForUser} displaySwipe = {this._displaySwipe}/>}
          numColumns={numColumns}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I use `this.state.dataSource` in `Profil` component in order to `.map` the swiper with the data ?

Comment: are you facing problem with passing the value to profile component ??'

Comment: Yes, i can&#39;t pass the entire dataSource in Profil component

Comment: But, You have to declared your `displayPosition` method yet.

Comment: No I have declared displayPosition but I didn't wrote it here, because otherwise it will be too long

Answer (score 0):

For passing values from one component to another, you can use the below code -

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('<Your Screen Name>', {
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource
});
```

Now in your component you can access datastore just like below :

```
var tempDataSource = [...this.props.navigation.state.params.dataSource]
```

> use it by accessing
>   ***this.props.navigation.state.params.dataSource*** this variable directly or you can save it in another variable just like above and
>   use it with your swiper.

I hope this helps, thanks :)

Comment: Can I add this anywhere in `Home` Component ?

Comment: profile and home both are different screens or you are calling profile inside homescreen ??

Comment: They are differents Screens. When I click on a profile in `Home` component, it will send me to `UserProfil`

Comment: ok then.... on click's *on press* in homescreen you have to provide the first code of mine and then on another screen i.e the profile screen you have to access the datasource using my second code @SauceCurry

Comment: I got `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` when I try to console log `tempDataSource`

Comment: @SauceCurry use this variable this.props.navigation.state.params.dataSource.....have you defined the tempDatasource globally ?